# What media player has speed and sound increase?

Tags: windows, media-player

What media player has speed and volume increase?

At the moment i only know of VLC which does up to ~32x speed and 400% volume. What other options do i have?

I am using windows7

Answer (score 1):

Foobar 2000 with the Soundtouch plugin will do what you want.

Go to http://www.foobar2000.org/ to download Foobar 2000, and http://acropolis.lokalen.org/ to download the SoundTouch DSP.  It will allow you to speed up the tempo by 100%, allow you to adjust pitch, and the rate.  It's a good quality processor, so the audio playback is about as clean as it will get.

Its biggest drawback is the lack of a friendly GUI control.  You have to open File/preferences, select Playback/DSP manager, select SoundTouch, then click Configure Selected.  Controlling the dialog adjusts the sound in real-time, so you can at least play with it during playback, but it's not convenient.

I'm with the other posters, though, too.  The more recent versions of VLC work really well at speeding up playback while preserving pitch.  It's not a bad option.

Answer (score 0):

[Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/) was the first media player I found that could increase the playback speed without also increasing the pitch of the audio. Of course once VLC changed their variable playback function to not affect the pitch, I’ve used that almost exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

Winamp or maybe Media Monkey all have that functionality if not built in then with plugins.

Why doesn't VLC fit the purpose is there other requirements?